# Why I received a message after the commit command on gitbash

Tags: git, github, git-bash, commit, git-commit

I've created a repository on git hub, after I run git bash on mey java project and a executed the following commands:

```
git init
git add .
git commit -m "MENSAGEM"
```

but after commit I received the message:

```
*On branch main
nothing to commit, working tree clean*
```

[image: git bash printSc]

I've tried this

```
git remote set-url origin https://github.com/renantins/test.git
```

but didn't work.

Comment: Is the local repository empty, with only `.git` and nothing else? If it's not empty, did you clone and create it?

Comment: The remote doesn't matter, `commit` doesn't interact with it. Try to run `git status` both before and after `git add`, it usually tells if there are files which can be staged/added, and afterwards if there are files which have been staged which are ready to be commited. If no files are there try `ls` to see if there is anything in the directory. If there are check the content of your .gitignore.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your description you issued the `git commit` command twice (first with 'MENSAGEM' as the comment) that is why the second commit says there is nothing to commit. Just confirm your commit is there with `git log`. You can ammend your last commit it if you wish to change the commit message.

To go further, github recommends `git remote add origin https://....git` (the instruction given in the newly created repo in github). Check the origin of your repo with `git remote -v`. If it looks OK, then `git push -u origin main`. That's it.

Well, almost it ;-). In my case I also need to esablish a token because user/pass login is not supported any longer by github.